# Drawing values from normal distribution to be used in Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: python, function, numpy, gaussian, montecarlo

I have defined a function, where the output is produced by a Monte Carlo Simulation. 
When I make the call `y(p,m,n,d)`, the output always stays the same "n" --> y = n

What am I doing wrong?

```
k = [0, 100]

for i in k:
    p = np.random.normal(40,3,i)
    m = np.random.normal(35,1,i)
    n = np.random.normal(50,4,i)
    d = np.random.normal(27,2.5,i)


def fct(p,m,n,d):
    global u1
    global u2
    if np.any( n > 0):
        return n
    u1, u2 = np.asarray[np.log(0.6*n)], np.asarray[(math.e**d)**0.5]
    if np.any(u1 != 0):
        return u1
    if np.any(u2 != 0):
        return u2
    if np.any( p > 0):
        return p    
    G = np.log(p**2) + np.asarray(6*[math.e**(-m)]/u1) + 3/u2
    return G

y = fct(p,m,n,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always hitting this case:

```
 if np.any( n > 0):
    return n
```

This is happening because of the way you define n:

```
n = np.random.normal(50,4,i)
```

The mean is at 50 and the standard deviation is 4. So, you have a range between 46 and 54 which will contain only positive values.